# Use variable to find json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

I'm trying to use a variable to match an id inside an array

There are 10 arrays under players and I want to cycle through all of them to see if my variable matches the id. If it does, It should use that array to and show the objects.

```
async function showMatch() {
// My variable
let userid = 71471603
let Response = await fetch(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/1e96uo`);
let matchlist = await Response.json();

}
showMatch();
```

So it should go cycle each `matchlist.players[0 to 9].id`, to see if it matches my userid variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
const animals = [
    {
        "name": "cat",
        "size": "small",
        "weight": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "dog",
        "size": "small",
        "weight": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "lion",
        "size": "medium",
        "weight": 150
    },
    {
        "name": "elephant",
        "size": "big",
        "weight": 5000
    }
];

let filterArray = animals.filter((animal) => {return animal.size === 'small'});
console.log(filterArray);// Returns an array which satisfies the match
```

Use `.filter` to filter out the values you are looking for from an array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
async function showMatch() {
  const userid = 71471603
  const Response = await fetch(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/1e96uo`);
  const matchlist = await Response.json();

  return matchlist.players.filter(player => players.id === userid)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
console because you can't return from a promise function (except using then)

```
 console.log(matchList.players.filter(player => player.id === userid)[0])
```

**Long answer:** if you execute this code in your **console** it will console the information for:

1- **EspartaN**

2- **Elsa**

```
async function showMatch(idOfSpecificUser) {
  // idOfSpecificUser: the id of the user you want his/her information
  // make the GET request
  let response = await fetch(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/1e96uo`);
  // convert the response to JSON
  let responseToJson = await response.json();
  // take the players array from the response after convert it to JSON
  let playersArrayOfObject = responseToJson.players;
  // console.log(playersArrayOfObject); // => [ {}, {}, {}, ... ]

  // now the real fun start
  // you need to iterate over this array and get the user data
  // why [0] cause filter return to you array of object (we need the first match)
  // or the only one match // => [ {id: 71471603, username: "EspartaN", .....} ]
  let userInfo = playersArrayOfObject.filter(
    user => user.id === idOfSpecificUser
  )[0];


  console.log(userInfo.username); //=> "EspartaN"
  console.log(userInfo); // => { id: 71471603, username: "EspartaN", ..... }
}

// => "EspartaN"
showMatch(71471603);

// => "Elsa"
showMatch(97531);
```

If you need any explanation, or this is not what you are asking about, please comment on my answer